# How to handle non-max value ties in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I was given a database with the request to print out the top ten values of the database unless there was a tie - if there was a tie then print out all the values that tied with the 10th value. I read up a lot on handling ties with `MAX` and `WITH TIES`, but I can't seem to find a solution for printing out ties for something that is not a maximum value and using `WITH TIES` does not seem to help me. Is there some simple way to do this or do I have to step through some hoops?

For example, my database contains

```
10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2
```

The result I'm currently getting is with `LIMIT 10`, where my result is:

```
10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7
```

But I would like for my program to return

```
10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
```

Would there be any way to do this?

Comment: Can you add an example dataset and the example output you want?

Comment: I've just updated the thread. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `rank()` [window function](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions) (Requires sqlite 3.25 or newer):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE x(v INTEGER);
sqlite> INSERT INTO x VALUES (10),(10),(10),(10),(9),(9),(9),(9),(8),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(2);
sqlite> SELECT v, rnk
   ...> FROM (SELECT v, rank() OVER (ORDER BY v DESC) AS rnk FROM x)
   ...> WHERE rnk <= 10
   ...> ORDER BY rnk;
v           rnk
----------  ----------
10          1
10          1
10          1
10          1
9           5
9           5
9           5
9           5
8           9
7           10
7           10
7           10
7           10
7           10
```

After sorting the numbers, each group of identical numbers is given the same ranking, with the next group's rank based on the total number of rows so far - why the 9's are rank 5 instead of 2 (For that behavior, use `dense_rank()` instead).

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be any way to do this?

I believe that the following will do what you want :-

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE val >= (SELECT min(val) FROM  (SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 10));
```

- obviously the tablename **mytable** and the column name **val** may have to be changed to suit your table and column names.

That is the innermost query returns the 10 highest rows from which the lowest value is obtained, this driving the WHERE clause of the primary query.

## Example/Demo

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (val INTEGER);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (10), (10), (10), (10), (9), (9), (9), (9), (8), (7), (7), (7), (7), (7), (2);
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE val >= (SELECT min(val) FROM  (SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 10));
```

results in :-

[image]

If you actually wanted the result to be ***10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7*** as a single row then you could use :-

```
SELECT group_concat(val) FROM mytable WHERE val >= (SELECT min(val) FROM  (SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 10));
```